# Is there a shortcut to unwrap or continue in a loop?

Tags: loops, rust, pattern-matching, control-flow

Consider this:

```
loop {
    let data = match something() {
        Err(err) => {
            warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", err);
            continue;
        },
        Ok(x) => x
    };

    let data2 = match something_else() {
        Err(err) => {
            warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", err);
            continue;
        },
        Ok(x) => x
    };

    // and so on
}
```

If I didn't need to assign the ok-value to `data`, I'd use `if let Err(err) = something()`, but is there a shortcut to the code above that'd avoid copy-pasting the Err/Ok branches on this, I think, typical scenario? Something like the `if let` that would also return the ok-value.

Comment: You could get rid of the `let data` and the `continue` and then just put "other stuff" inside the `Ok(x) =>` case.

Comment: @sepp2k True, but that'll quickly turn into a lot of nested code when there're multiple resultish operations inside the loop. Would writing a macro be a way out?

Comment: "avoid copy-pasting the Err/Ok branches on this" what is copy-pasted here?

Comment: You are missing the point of struct like `Result`, this force code to check the error, if there was something to bypass this, what would be the point ? This construct is so frequent in Rust that `?` is used to avoid copy of code. For **test only or in main function**, you can use `.unwrap()` or `.expect()`

Comment: I'm not going to edit the question, but I think the title would be more appropriate as "How do I concisely compose Results?" - It seems like your question isn't specifically about `if let`, seeing as that it's effectively seeking an alternative to the language construct.

Comment: One way to concisely compose `Result`s is to use one of the comprehension crates like [map_for](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) or [mdo](https://crates.io/crates/mdo). (Note: I'm the author of `map_for`)

Comment: @mcarton added the copy/paste

Comment: @BHustus true, fixed that

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not bypassing the result or error handling, but trying to avoid the copy-paste of the same error handling logic over and over again. Question title better reflects this now I hope, sorry.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While I think that E_net4's answer is probably the best one, I'm adding a macro for posterity in case creating a separate function and early-returning with the `?` operator is for some reason undesirable.

Here is a simple `skip_fail!` macro that `continue`s a containing loop when passed an error:

```
macro_rules! skip_fail {
    ($res:expr) => {
        match $res {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(e) => {
                warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", e);
                continue;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This macro can be used as `let ok_value = skip_fail!(do_something());`

[Playground link which uses skip_fail to print out numbers divisible by 1, 2, and 3, and print an error when one of the divisions would truncate.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fecf1b774f5252cbb5ed2a0d0df3c17d&version=stable)

Again, I believe that using `?` in a separate function, and returning an `Ok(end_result)` if nothing fails, is probably the most idiomatic solution, so if you can use that answer you probably should.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps with encapsulating array access.

Answer (score 26):

Rust [1.65.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements) add `let-else` statements. So you can write it this way:

```rust
    loop {
        let data = something()
        let Ok(ok_data) = data else {
            warn!("skipped.");
            continue;
        };
        // ok_data is available here
        let Ok(data2) = something_else(ok_data) else {
            continue;
        };
        // and so on
    }
```

But you won't have access to the `err` variable

Answer (score 13):

If you are going to "unwrap or continue" on results often, consider encapsulating that logic in a separate function. With it, you can take advantage of the `?` syntax to raise errors out of the function. The loop's flow logic can then be written in a single place (although at this point, you might no longer need the `continue`).

```
loop {
    if let Err(err) = do_event() {
        warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", err);
        // continue; // you also don't need this
    }
}

fn do_event() -> Result<(), YourErrorType> {
    let data = do_something()?; // 
    let x = something_more()?;  // error propagation!
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Worth noting, I believe you could also do this with a closure as well, if you don't want to make an entirely separate function in another part of your source code. Though I don't know how good that would look...

Comment: @BHustus Indeed, but I believe that a separate function is easier to read here. :)

Comment: that will look ugly if do_event return something you need? and you have to unwrap the result after check error?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your questions @Sean, but no, raising errors from a result via `?` is fairly clean and idiomatic, as presented. And at the top of the calling chain, a good end user application would have a suitable _error reporter_, presenting the error in a human readable fashion. Consider looking at the `eyre` and `miette` crates for examples of error reporting libraries, and this [overview video on error handling in Rust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzC7H83aDZc).

Comment: @E_net4thecandidatesupporter sorry that my question confuse you, I mean, if do_event() has some value to return instead of (), may be some code can demonstrate https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=248ae38826cecc369cb07476753b8a60

Comment: @Sean If a final outcome is expected outside the loop, then sure, the top level logic can be tweaked to use a `match` instead of `if let`. A macro can also be built to do this, as hinted by another answer. However, if the point is merely to continue processing the data inside that loop step, then this pattern expects you to extend that logic inside `do_event` itself.

Answer (score 6):

If you have to chain multiple `Ok`s together, need to use one `Ok`'s value in the next operation, and don't care about *where* in the chain the error arises, consider [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then):

```
loop {
    let outcome = something()
                  .and_then(|a| something_else(a))
                  .and_then(|a| another_thing(a))
                  .and_then(|a| {
                      let b = a + salt;
                      one_more(b)
                  });
    if let Err(e) = outcome {
        warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", e);
    }
}
```

Where `something`, `something_else`, `another_thing` and `one_more` all return some form of `Result`. Even though this example removes the `continue` statement, `and_then` effectively emulates it by short-circuiting when the `Result` is of type `Err`. All further calls down the line will be skipped over.

You can make this even more concise by using non-closures on the statements that only require one function call:

```
loop {
    let outcome = something()
                  .and_then(something_else)
                  .and_then(another_thing)
                  .and_then(|a| one_more(a + salt));
    if let Err(e) = outcome {
        warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", e);
    }
}
```

(Note the lack of parentheses on the functions, which indicates they're being used as callable objects rather than taking their return value)

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using unstable features, you can use a try block for this:

```
#![feature(try_blocks)]

pub fn something() -> Result<String, String> {
    Err(String::from("Badness"))
}

pub fn something_else() -> Result<String, String> {
    Ok(String::from("Ok"))
}

pub fn main() {
    loop {
        let result: Result<(), String> = try {
            let data = something()?;
            let data2 = something_else()?;
        };
        if let Err(e) = result {
            println!("An error: {}; skipped.", e)
        }
    }
}
```

As shepmaster mentions in the comments this can be done without any unstable featurtes using a closure which is immediately evaluated (an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE for short). This is the modification to the solution by E_net4 proposed by MutantOctopus in that solutions comments.

```
pub fn something() -> Result<String, String> {
    Err(String::from("Badness"))
}

pub fn something_else() -> Result<String, String> {
    Ok(String::from("Ok"))
}

pub fn main() {
    loop {
        let result: Result<(), String> = (|| {
            let data = something()?;
            let data2 = something_else()?;
            Ok(())
        })();
        if let Err(e) = result {
            println!("An error: {}; skipped.", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [An IIFE is the stable equivalent](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c6af7747193cfa30c105084d4c3c2d7), which is effectively the same as pointed out in [E_net4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785300/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster that's neat. I've added that code to the question. But out of interest what does IIFE stand for?

Comment: [Immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [unwrap_or](https://lib.rs/crates/unwrap_or) crate to accomplish this.

You can use it to make nice and clean code:

```
unwrap_or_ok!(callable(&mut param), _, return);

loop {
    let data = unwrap_ok_or!(something(), err, {
        warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", err);
        continue;
    });

    let data2 = unwrap_ok_or!(somethingElse(), err, {
        warn!("An error: {}; skipped.", err);
        continue;
    });
}
```